# node ssh-exec pipe in cron fails

Tags: node.js, ssh, cron

I have code dev-repcert.js which runs but not in cron. It is fine in cron only after I comment pipe(exec) part. I know because I got that email.send()

```
[root@node dev-test]# crontab -l
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/node /home/dev-test/dev-repcert.js > /dev/null 2>&1
```

dev-repcert.js

```
var exec = require('ssh-exec');
var fs = require('fs');
var test = true;
var email = require('./mailer');

file = fs.createWriteStream('rep-output.txt');
/*process.stdin
    .pipe(exec(command, host))
    .pipe(file);*/

email.send();
```

Comment: did you try changing working directory? Try this: `cd /home/dev-test/ && * * * * * /usr/bin/node /home/dev-test/dev-repcert.js > /dev/null 2>&1 `

Comment: oh btw, how are you going to send input if you are running it from cron !?

Comment: tried  * * * * * cd /home/dev-test/ && /usr/bin/node /home/dev-test/dev-repcert.js > /dev/null 2>&1, no difference. Program reads from mongo monthly and schedules tasks. I think to use forever and maybe to restart it montlhy in cron ?